# Unexpected socket close error for nodemailer by outlook

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

I use nodemailer to build email server with outlook. this is my code

```
 let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.office365.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false, 
  auth: {
    user: "username",
    pass: "password"
  },
  "tls":{"ciphers":"SSLv3"}
});
let options={from:'xxx.@xxx.com', to:‘xxxx’,subject:'',text:''}
transporter.sendMail(options, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
  })
```

but when I run ,it throw 'Unexpected socket close 'in nodemailer

Comment: Port 587 ist probably the secure port, and you use  secure: false ?

Comment: yes, I use secure : false ,secure: false is used for not 465 port . and i also try secureConnection: false ,but not success too, the security port you mean is not accessible?